# Razor RenderSection throwing error if not defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Using `@RenderSection("SectionName", false)`, why do I need to explicitly set the 2nd parameter to `false` when the Intellisense already states that the default is false?

**Update:**
[image: is the tool tip wrong?]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The RTM signature of the [`RenderSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg537886(v=VS.99).aspx) method is:

```
public HelperResult RenderSection(string name, bool required)
```

There also exists an override that looks like this:

```
public HelperResult RenderSection(string name) {
    return RenderSection(name, required: true);
}
```

Note that this method no longer uses default parameters, instead opting for explicit overrides.

The signature of this method changed twice during the development of MVC 3 which explains why you might be seeing confusing examples.

**Edit**: It appears that the MVC 3 RTM documentation is incorrect and erroneously references a default value of the `required` parameter.

Comment: Look at my update, what is meant by `The default is false` or do I just outdated documentation?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. The documentation is outdated. I'll ping the MSDN folks to get it updated.

Comment: So the documentation is outdated in the RTM? If so, please update your answer so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

it needs to be true. You are saying that the section is optional.

@RenderSection("SectionName", true)

or
@RenderSection("SectionName", optional: true)

Comment: Do I have an older version of MVC 3? Because I see the parameter as `required` not `optional`. Is my intellisense old?

Comment: Actually both of you have outdated (i.e. non-RTM) versions of ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: My bad.. it is "required". The answer is we are using named parameters and not optional parameters. Therefore you *have* to specify the default value of the second parameter.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx